# How do I differentiate b/w a ipfs url/path (content-addressed) from normal-url (location-addressed)?

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, ipfs

I am trying to fetch nft-metadata for the nfts added on my platform. Some Nfts contains ipfs-urls as their tokenURIs and I need a mechanism to differentiate them from normal-urls (location-addressed urls).

I was using **is-ipfs**, but it gives false returns even for valid ipfs-urls!

```
if (mtokenUri) {
  var res;
  var data;

  console.log("### ipfs url check ###");
  console.log(
    isIPFS.urlOrPath(
      "ipfs://bafybeihbsysdkemc3kyylegtfopkrcfiih4exnasoql2q36fb4zawlrwhy/volcano.json",
    ),
  );
  // false for "ipfs://bafybeihbsysdkemc3kyylegtfopkrcfiih4exnasoql2q36fb4zawlrwhy/volcano.json"

  //this is not very reliable
  if (isIPFS.urlOrPath(mtokenUri)) {
    //gives false even for a valid ipfs-url
    console.log("inside erc721 ipfs: ");

    isIpfsUrl = true;
    console.log("*** 721 isIpfs url ***");
    console.log(isIPFS.urlOrPath(mtokenUri));
    // example ccid = 'QmPzhc9ezphJ85qJWfVVpeHkPieDJznpYduGhMYD7Z4Ac9'
    const cid_eg2 =
      "bafybeihbsysdkemc3kyylegtfopkrcfiih4exnasoql2q36fb4zawlrwhy/volcano.json";
    try {
      res = await ipfs.cat(mtokenUri);
      // data = await res.json()
      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    //shows:cat {<suspended>}
  } else {
    //do normal fetch

    try {
      res = await fetch(mtokenUri);
      data = await res.json();

      console.log("erc721 normal fetch");
      console.log("*** Normal fetch data *** ");

      console.log(data);
      _imageUrl = data.image;
      _name = data.name;
      _description = data.description;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to fetch a ipfs-url using 'fetch', it shows-

[image]

> Is there any way to do this efficiently/reliably?

Comment: I mean... you could just start with `if(mtokenUri.startsWith('ipfs://'))`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AKX for the input.
Using this for now-

```
  if (
      isIPFS.urlOrPath(theUri) ||
      mtokenUri.startsWith('ipfs://') ||
      mtokenUri.includes('/ipfs/') ||
      mtokenUri.includes('/bafy')
     ) { 
       // parse/cat ipfs-url
       } else { 
        // parse/fetch normal-non-ipfs-url
       }
```